# Python excel to csv copying column data with different header names

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl, sublist

So here is my situation. Using Python I want to copy specific columns from excel `spreadsheet` into specific columns into a `csv` worksheet.

The pre-filled column header names are named differently in each spreadsheet and I need to use a sublist as a parameter.

For example, in the first sublist, data column in excel needs to be copied from/to:

```
spreadsheet      csv
"scan_date" => "date_of_scan"
```

Two sublists as parameters: one of names copied from excel, one of names of where to paste into csv.

Not sure if a dictionary sublist would be better than two individual sublists?

Also, the `csv` column header names are in row B (not row A like excel) which has complicated things such as data frames.

So, ideally I would like to have sublists converted to arrays,

- spreadsheet iterates columns to find `"scan_date"`
- copies data
- iterates to find `"date_of_scan"` in csv
- paste data
- moves on to the second item in the sublists and repeats.

I've tried `pandas` and `openpyxl` and just can't seem to figure out the approach/syntax of how to do it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you.

Clarification edit:
The csv file has some preexisting data within. Also, I cannot change the headers into different columns. So, if "date_of_scan" is in column "RF" then it must stay in column "RF". I was able to copy, say, the 5 columns of data from excel into a temp spreadsheet and then concatenate into the csv but it always moved the pasted columns to the beginning of the csv document (columns A, B, C, D, E).

Comment: This is a really good post, nice work, will try to answer. One thing that could help the post is a header of 5 rows of sample data from the excel sheet and the csv you want.

Comment: To answer part of your question, yes a dictionary where the `key` is the excel column name that maps to the `value` which is the csv column name. You would then iterate over the keys in the dictionary and don't have to worry about the data in the two lists "lining up"

Comment: You should include whatever code you've already written. This should be pretty straighforward.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to know the answer without seeing you specific dataset, but it seems to me that a simpler approach might be to simply make your excel sheet a `df`, drop everything except the columns you want in the `csv` then write a `csv` with pandas. Here's some psuedo-code.

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.read_excel('your_file_name.xlsx')

drop_cols=[,,,]  #list of columns to get rid of

df.drop(drop_cols,axis='columns')


col_dict={'a':'x','b':'y','c':'z'} #however you want to map you new columns in this example abc are old columns and xyz are new ones


#this line will actually rename your columns with the dictionary
df=df.rename(columns=col_dict)


df.to_csv('new_file_name.csv')  #write new file
```

and this will actually run in python, but I created the df from dummy data instead of an excel file.

```
#with dummy data
df=pd.DataFrame([0,1,2],index=['a','b','c']).T
col_dict={'a':'x','b':'y','c':'z'}
df=df.rename(columns=col_dict)
df.to_csv('new_file_name.csv')  #write new file
```

Comment: No need for Pandas. openpyxl in read-only mode can be chained with csv writer.

Comment: I guess one clarification I needed from the author is whether it's really necessary to modify an existing csv, or whether you all the data that goes into the csv is already in the excel file. I think the pandas solution is straightforward if it is the latter case, and my person preference is not to edit files is possible so as not to corrupt them b mistake.

Comment: I agree with you on the non-destructive approach, but for really large files Pandas' in-memory approach is a hindrance and it's parallelism is limited, ie. where the file format matters more than the excellent manipulation and analysis that Pandas provides.